# Add z-index to Google Maps API v3 autocomplete search box

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using [Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) from Google Maps API v3 and I am trying to get the search box to be placed over a DIV. This DIV has a `z-index` on 200 000 and the background of this DIV has a `z-index` on 100 000.

CSS:

```
.dim-page-view-background {
    background-color : rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    background-image : url(../../images/backgrounds/lined.png);
    display : none;
    height : 100%;
    left : 0;
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    width : 100%;
    z-index : 100000;
}

.dim-page-view-content {
    background-color : #ffffff;
    border-radius : 10px;
    display : none;
    margin-left : 20px;
    padding : 25px 30px;
    position : absolute;
    text-align : justify;
    top : 60px;
    width : 500px;
    z-index : 200000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dim-page-view-background"></div>
<div class="dim-page-view-content"></div>

<input type="text" name="textfield-address" id="search-place">
```

JavaScript:

```
function google_maps() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var input = (document.getElementById('#search-place'));
    var search_field = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));

    map_options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.4, 13.5),
        draggable: true,
        zoom: 4,
        minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 18,
        panControl: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id_google_maps), map_options);


    google.maps.event.addListener(search_field, 'places_changed', function() {
        // Run my code
    });
}
```

I hope you got all the code you'll need :) How can I get the search result to be visible over the `dim-page-view-background` and `dim-page-view-content` DIVs? [Demo](http://server-1.myftp.org/vadret-justnu/62.835089,15.249023) (click on the cog in the menu top of the website and type some place in the text field with the placeholder "Sök efter en plats (resultatet är gömd bakom innehållet, så det måste fixas)").

Comment: please define "over"!

Comment: So the autocomplete search box is visible and not behind the DIV

Comment: In your Demo the autocomplete is visible and not behind anything(I can type in it, so it's in front). When you mean the list with the suggestions you must set the desired z-index for the selector `.pac-container`

Comment: Yes. I meant the suggestion list :) Sorry. Thank you! That worked :)